# Realtime rendering using a ray tracing engine

Tags: rendering, 3d-meshes, raytracing

I want to render an object that has a mesh with one million hexagonal elements(100 * 100 * 100).

Lights, shadows and textures is not important and each element has a solid color. 
and finally, the actions I want to have, is simply rotating the object, zooming and panning.

I am wondering what ray tracing engine is better for my conditions. or, do I have to take another approach?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since lights and shadows are not important, I'd suggest going with any 3D engine that works with your programming language. Raytracing would be overkill and certainly slower than hardware acceleration.

Comment: for example openGL? or directX? I have to write my code with Java, but I think for complex mesh, JOGL is a little slow.

Comment: OpenGL and DirectX are just interfaces to the graphics hardware. They are difficult to learn and you don't want to deal with them directly for your application.

3D Engines, on the other hand, use DirectX or OpenGL and provide a simple and easy-to-use interface. Do a google search for "java 3d engines" and pick whatever looks easy to use.